# Bitcoin rig setup, connecting a Butterfly Labs unit using USB

Tags: asic, mining-setup

I'm currently running a rig with seven block erupters in a 10 connector powered USB hub. After taking the USB fan into account, I have an additional two USB ports available. The host is an old laptop.

I've just purchased a [Butterfly Labs](https://products.butterflylabs.com/) 30 Ghash/s unit. What is the best way to combine this into my rig?

Can I plug it into the USB port, even though the Butterfly Labs 30 Ghash/s unit is self-powered? Otherwise, should I connect the Butterfly Lab unit directly to a USB port on the laptop? Will there be any difference?

I'm mining with [CGMiner](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/CGMiner).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will make a difference.  If you are using the [Anker 10-port "power bar" style USB hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005NGQWL2) (that's what it sounds like you have, based on your description of it + the fact that this hub is very commonly used with USB bitcoin miners), that is a pretty robust hub.  One of my mining rigs (which doubles as my media center) has 8 block erupters + USB fan + an external USB hard drive on it, and all devices function without any difficulty.